# How to route files in subdirectory on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now, I have a landing page (home.html.erb) that is rendered with the "home" action in my "static_pages controller", and on this landing page, there is a nav bar with the following:
  "features" button when hover displays:
  a) web
  b) mobile.

How and what do I need to include in my routes.rb file and controller.rb file so that my home page renders  /features/web   when I click on the web button?

Comment: /features/web is this another action of some another controller.

Comment: No. this is being rendered with bootstrap in my "home.html.erb" file.

Comment: The controller I have is the following:

Comment: So this is home.html.erb page?

Comment: Yes. The only controller I have right now is static_pages_controller.rb with the following:     class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

Answer (score 0):

In routes: 
`get 'web', to 'featuresController#web'`

for your button:`<%= link_to 'Web', web_path, class:"button" %>`

In your featuresController:

```
def web
end
```

and have a view called `views/features/web.html.erb`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your route file

```
root "static_pages#home" 
  get '/features/web' => 'static_pages#web', as: :web
```

This will make this your root path

Add this to your view

```
<%= link_to 'Web', web_path, class:"button" %>
```

Add this to your controller

```
def web

end
```

And create a page

```
views/static_pages/web.html.erb
```

Comment: This would just keep sending the user back to the 'landing page'

Comment: You want to send him to /features/web page. Have you created any action or any page for it.

Comment: Yup, I have already done this. What do I need to do to make my url "features/web" (which is activated when I click on the features/web button) display content?

Comment: Check my answer now. I have explained everything.

Comment: Hi, that was great. But is it possible to put my web.html.erb inside my features subdirectory that lives inside my static_pages directory, so that my url 'features/web' is fired up with views/static_pages/features/web.html.erb?

Comment: Nope we do't do it like that. Don't worry your URL will be /features/web